# How to disable modal segue iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I have an app having 7 screen. On the screen 7 i have a button that does valiation and submits data and then it jumps to screen 1 using modal segue.
But ,I only want to move screen1 if the validation succeeds or else i dont want to move to screen1.
Currently its moving to screen 1 independent of validation.

button click code is as below

```
- (IBAction)submitButtonActionForDemo:(id)sender
{
    if (![JLTValidator validateFields:@[_authRepresentative, _acceptDeclarationStatement,_homeTeamRepName,_homeTeamRepPosition,_awayTeamRepName,_awayTeamRepPosition]])
    {
       // how to disable a modal segue here.
        return; 
    }
}
```

JLTValidator is my validating class here.

Pls suggest/help. Thanks in adv.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to only allow the segue some times, you need to "name" the segue in InterfaceBuilder, then implement this routine:

```
- (BOOL)shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier sender:(id)sender {
    if ([identifier isEqualToString:@"your segue name"]) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```